# Wrapping namespaced custom types defined only in headers with SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

How can i wrap this content using SWIG?

usecase5.h

```
#ifndef __USECASE5_H__
#define __USECASE5_H__

#include <math.h>

namespace foo_namespace {
    struct vec2
    {
        int x, y;

        vec2() {}

        explicit vec2( int a, int b )
        {
            x = a;
            y = b;
        }

        vec2 & operator =( vec2  const & v ) { x = v.x;  y = v.y;  return *this; }
        vec2 & operator/=( vec2  const & v ) { x /= v.x; y /= v.y; return *this; }

        vec2 xx() const { return vec2(x,x); }
    }
}

#endif
```

usecase6.h

```
#ifndef __USECASE6_H__
#define __USECASE6_H__

#include "usecase5.h"

namespace foo_namespace {
    vec2  usecase6_f1(const vec2 & x);
}

#endif
```

usecase6.cpp

```
namespace foo_namespace {
    vec2  usecase6_f1(const vec2 & x)
    {
        x = vec2();
    }
}
```

example.i

```
// GENERATED BY gen_swig.py at 2016-10-04 21:46

%module example

%{
//#include "usecase1.h"
//#include "usecase2.h"
//#include "usecase3.h"
//#include "usecase4.h"
#include "usecase5.h"
#include "usecase6.h"

using namespace foo_namespace;
%}

//%include "usecase1.h"
//%include "usecase2.h"
//%include "usecase3.h"
//%include "usecase4.h"
%include "usecase5.h"
%include "usecase6.h"
```

After trying that naive example.i with `swig -python -c++ example.i` I'll get:

```
usecase5.h(19) : Warning 362: operator= ignored
usecase5.h(24) : Error: Syntax error in input(3).
```

So, how could I wrap this little dummy c++ example?

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon at the end of your struct definition in usecase5.h

Comment: @JakeCobb Nice catch! I've edited again :)

Comment: @JakeCobb Thanks to your catch I've been able to fix the stuff, it wasn't swig problem after-all so I've self answered. If you want to receive the validation just add your answer, you deserve it to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this wasn't any issue related with swig but more on the c++ side, to fix it I just needed to fix the c++ issues:

usecase5.h

```
#ifndef __USECASE5_H__
#define __USECASE5_H__

#include <math.h>

namespace foo_namespace {
    struct vec2
    {
        int x, y;

        vec2() {}

        explicit vec2( int a, int b )
        {
            x = a;
            y = b;
        }

        vec2 & operator =( vec2  const & v ) { x = v.x;  y = v.y;  return *this; }
        vec2 & operator/=( vec2  const & v ) { x /= v.x; y /= v.y; return *this; }

        vec2 xx() const { return vec2(x,x); }
    };
}

#endif
```

usecase6.cpp

```
#include "usecase5.h"

namespace foo_namespace {
    vec2  usecase6_f1(const vec2 & x)
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

After that the wrapper will be built succesfully and working properly on the python side.